# Increasing the msg.payload[i] variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have a MySQL database with two columns: **Username** and **Password**. I want to list usernames one by one.

[image: My Flow]

The first function holds my database query:

```
msg.topic = "SELECT * FROM userlog";
return msg;
```

The second function loops until it displays all database usernames. `maxarray` is the maximum number of usernames in my database.

```
var maxarray = global.get("maxarray");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < maxarray; i++) {
    msg.payload = msg.payload[i].Username;
    node.send(msg);
}

return;
```

Whenever I run this, it gives me an error:

> `"TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined"`

Here's my flow if you would like to import.

```
[{"id":"213ba9d6.1ba576","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"820a48f5.ff49d8","type":"debug","z":"213ba9d6.1ba576","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":490,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"673daf0e.c65b8","type":"inject","z":"213ba9d6.1ba576","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"\"SELECT * FROM userlog\"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":100,"y":100,"wires":[["3724e918.bf5b86"]]},{"id":"dbe2587d.cfb7a8","type":"mysql","z":"213ba9d6.1ba576","mydb":"f1e0508e.13503","name":"db","x":290,"y":100,"wires":[["fd991622.c20928"]]},{"id":"3724e918.bf5b86","type":"function","z":"213ba9d6.1ba576","name":"msg.topic","func":"msg.topic = \"SELECT * FROM userlog\";\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":180,"y":140,"wires":[["dbe2587d.cfb7a8"]]},{"id":"fd991622.c20928","type":"function","z":"213ba9d6.1ba576","name":"for loop","func":"var i;\nvar array;\nfor (i = 0; i < msg.payload.length; i++) {\n    msg.payload = array[i].Username;\n    node.send(msg);\n}\nreturn;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":380,"y":140,"wires":[["820a48f5.ff49d8"]]},{"id":"f1e0508e.13503","type":"MySQLdatabase","name":"","host":"127.0.0.1","port":"3306","db":"test dump","tz":"","charset":"UTF8"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a copy of `msg.payload` before the loop as you've replaced it before sending the `msg` object.

You should probably also be using the array length rather than trying to keep track in a global variable

```
var i;
var array = msg.payload

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    msg.payload = array[i].Username;
    node.send(msg);
}

return;
```

Comment: Hello :). I have used your code to update my flow but received an error.
`"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`

I updated the workflow. Can u try import again? :)

Comment: Try again, the code in the answer is right